# gnuplot: Row stacked bar graph with error bar

Tags: plot, gnuplot, histogram, bar-chart

I am new to gnuplot. I want to generate graph from data points with three components and standard deviation.
My data looks like this:

```
TYPE1   15  20  65  5
TYPE2   20  20  60  4
TYPE3   10  30  60  6
TYPE4   30  30  40  5
```

I want to plot a rowstacked bar for each TYPE with the 3 components stacked and an errobar at the top.
I wrote the following script to do this:

```
set terminal png
set output "sample.png"
set boxwidth 0.75 relative
set style fill   pattern 0 border
set style histogram rowstacked
set style data histograms
set xtics 1000 nomirror
set ytics 100 nomirror
set noytics
set mxtics 2
set mytics 2
set ytics 100
set yrange [0:150]
set ylabel "Y"
set xlabel "X"
set title "Sample graph"
plot 'data.dat' using (100*column(2)/(column(2)+column(3)+column(4))) t "A" , '' using (100*column(3)/(column(2)+column(3)+column(4))) t "B" , '' using (100*column(4)/(column(2)+column(3)+column(4))):xtic(1) t "C"
```

This produced a graph which looks like this: [image: Click Here].

But I am not able to get the errorbar on the top of each bar with deviation values in column 5. I tried different ways using rowstacked and errorbar styled bar graphs but had no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you must know, that with the `histogram` style the boxes are placed at the x-positions `0`, `1`, etc. i.e. at the row number.

So for the `errorbars` you must use `column(0)` as x-coordinate:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output "sample.png"

set boxwidth 0.75 relative
set style fill pattern 0 border
set style histogram rowstacked
set style data histograms

set yrange [0:150]

set macros
scale = '100/(column(2)+column(3)+column(4))'

set bars 2.0
plot 'data.dat' using ($2 * @scale):xtic(1) t "A" , \
     '' using ($3 * @scale) t "B" , \
     '' using ($4 * @scale) t "C",\
     '' using 0:(100):5 with errorbars notitle lw 2 lt -1
```

The result with 4.6.3 is:

[image]

For convenience I used a macro `scale`. The macros work as follows: You define a string, like `scale = '...'` in the script above. That can be used later in any expression as `@scale` (you must have `set macros` enabled). The content of the `scale` string is then replaced before the respective command is executed.